# access xp list showing last time an employees call was evaluated

Tags: sql, list, ms-access, filter

I work in the management staff of a call centre and I've created a "Call Evaluation Database" using access XP where an employees call can be rated on things such as customer service, knowledge, call control etc.
Part of this has now developed and I would like to add a form with a list showing all employees and next to their name only the LAST time a call was evaluated and the service it was for. this would be sorted in ascending order so we can see when a call was last evaluated and the people at the top would need theirs evaluating next.
I only want this to show their last call for each and every employee, not ALL of them. and I'm struggling to do this in a query.

I hope this makes sense, if not ill try answer any questions the best I can. its probably really simple but I don't class myself as an Access expert!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY. For example:

```
SELECT Employee.ID, Max(LastEval)
FROM Employees 
INNER JOIN Evaluations
ON Employee.ID = Evalutations.EmployeeID
GROUP BY Employee.ID
```

You can build such queries easily enough using the query design window and the sigma button Σ

**EDIT re comment**

```
SELECT a.[Evaluation Number],
       a.[CSO Name],
       a.service,
       a.[Date of call],
       a.[Name of Monitor],
       a.[Date Sheet Completed]
FROM   [KD call monitoring] a
WHERE  a.[Evaluation Number] 
IN (SELECT TOP 1 [Evaluation Number]
    FROM   [KD call monitoring] b
    WHERE  b.[CSO Name] = a.[CSO Name]
           AND b.[Date of Call] =
               (SELECT MAX([date of call])
                FROM   [KD call monitoring]
                WHERE
           [cso name] = a.[CSO Name])
    ORDER  BY [evaluation number])
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your quick reply. i think i kind of follow you.. this query would be based on the main table in my database and amongst various fields that cover call marking i have the fields [KD call monitoring].[Evaluation Number], [KD call monitoring].[CSO Name], [KD call monitoring].Service, [KD call monitoring].[Date of call], [KD call monitoring].[Name of Monitor], [KD call monitoring].[Date Sheet Completed]... 
i intend to have it sorted by "Date of Call" and the "CSO Name" is the employee name. how would your forumlae fit into this? cheers, Kris

Comment: there is also a 2nd table which simply lists all the employee names, apologies  cheers, Kris

Comment: Full disclosure is a good idea when posting questions. A vague question gets a vague answer.

Comment: re comment #2 it is a bit late for that. See if you can work it out for yourself from here.

Comment: as i mentioned previously i am not highly experienced in using Access XP or SQL code so your condescending attitude and rudeness is unnecessary. what is meant by the "a" and "b" figures in the formulae? and when you say "ORDER BY [EVALUATION NUMBER]" would that be the case even if i intend to order the list by "Date Sheet Completed" ??